# How to *** include *** source code within my macos Swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, module, frameworks

**This is for macOS. No iOS-specific answers, please.**

**How can I configure my macOS Framework project in Xcode to include / bundle / package all my source code so that it is available to all client projects that use the framework ?**

EDIT - I am the client of my own framework and I want to be able to open the framework source when developing using it.

To give an analogy of what I want, when you download a Java library as JAR, you often get **bin** and **src** folders within that JAR, and the Eclipse IDE is able to then show the source. In  other cases, you can download the source separately, and "Link to source" in Eclipse. That's what I want.

I've done TONS of research on Google, and found results for ***hiding*** source code, but none for ***showing*** it.

### My progress so far

I've successfully built my **macOS-only** Swift framework which contains a single public Swift class with a public init and all functions public.

I'm also able to import the framework's module successfully in my app project which uses the Swift class from the framework. All good. It compiles fine.

```
import MyFrameworkModule
let myObject: MyFrameworkClass = MyFrameworkClass()
```

### The problem

Now, **when I Cmd+Ctrl+Click on MyFrameworkClass in XCode**, I want it to open the source code of MyFrameworkClass from within MyModule. But, it opens a blank file with 2 empty lines, i.e. **no source code is shown.**

**How can I configure my macOS Framework project in Xcode to include / bundle / package all my source code so that it is available to all client projects that use the framework ?**

Comment: Select Embed & Sign or Embed Without Signing under the General tab?

Comment: Tried that, didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 0):

Once you build your framework, the only thing you should see is the public interface of your framework, all the information about your source files implementation private methods etc are lost.
And this due to the fact that what you compile become a mach-o file that contains your compiled framework. You can inspect you framework and also the binary part of it. The framework is just a directory by pointing to it you can see all contained resources and that mach-o file.
You can also inspect the Mach-o file, and if you do you will see that most of the informations are "lost", you see for instance that all your methods name and classes have been mangled.
If you want to share your source code just share it, they can integrate your framework project inside their project, in this case they will be able to have direct references to your source files.
Or you can use a dependency manager such as cocoa pods and basically sharing your source code and having the process of integration simplified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there are people out there complaining that their source code does show when their framework is used externally. How did they get that to work ? Look here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656610

Comment: If your framework has public methods, properties or classes  (and you need them as public to be used in a hosting app) they will be show in the interface file and that is how it works,you can't hide them.But Your implementations will not be exposed.
If you want to hide them you can create a fake interface that reads command (can be string, enumeration or classes) and just expose as public "execute" method.

Comment: If you have imported your project into another project and added it as dependency and with the shortcut you can see your implementation be aware that i won't happened if you distribute your library as a precompiled framework

Comment: Oh ok, i see. So that gives me an idea. Perhaps I can simply develop my app project by including the framework project as a dependency ? That way, I can see all the source code from the framework ?

Comment: Exactly... you have two projects: 1- the framework, 2-the hosting app.
You can integrate the framework in the hosting app, just by Drag&Drop the project file of the framework inside the project of the hosting app. Then you will probably need to set up the dependency. In this case you are able to see the full source code and debug your framework along with the hosting app. Just google for manually integrating iOS framework

Comment: Thanks for the help, Andrea ! Appreciate it :) I tried upvoting your answer but it won't let me because of my points score.

Comment: No problem glad to help :-)